# client_secret.json is empty upon download from google developer site

Tags: ruby, json, gmail-api

I am trying to download the client_secret.json from google API. I am following the steps listed in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby.

- Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically enable the API.
- In the sidebar on the left, select Consent screen. Select an EMAIL ADDRESS and enter a PRODUCT NAME if not already set and click the Save button.
- In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials and click Create new Client ID.
- Select the application type Installed application, the installed application type Other, and click the Create Client ID button.
- Click the Download JSON button under your new client ID. Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

The client_secret.json file does download but it is empty. The title of the file looks like it must be the client_id ending in apps.googleusercontent.com however there is no data stored inside the file.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.

Comment: Me too, this is frustrating.

Comment: Same here. I've tried Chrome and Firefox. Same result.

Comment: Same for me. I submitted feedback via the button on the top of the page because this is apparently a widespread issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this just pre-populates the json for you.   If you check out [API Client Library for Ruby (Alpha) - Client Secrets](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_client_secrets), you should be able to manually create it with the information on the same page that offers the "DOWNLOAD JSON" button.

Although this says it is for Ruby, I don't think the json format would be any different for other languages.

**Here is a snippet of the example from the above Google Reference URL:**

*Here is an example client_secrets.json file for a **web** application:*

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "asdfjasdljfasdkjf",
    "client_secret": "1912308409123890",
    "redirect_uris": ["https://www.example.com/oauth2callback"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

*Here is an example client_secrets.json file for an **installed** application:*

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "837647042410-75ifg...usercontent.com",
    "client_secret":"asdlkfjaskd",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes client_ID and client_secret are available in browser view and can be manually inputted into the sample json provided. This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be resolved now, as I can download them properly.